# タグシノニムの提案：os-x と mac

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案

現在[mac](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac)と[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)の二つのタグがあり、どちらもよく使われていますが、実際はMacOS Xに関する質問ばかりです。今後投稿される質問も殆どがそうでしょう。

というところで、英語版と同様 [os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) をマスターとしたシノニムを作成するのはどうでしょうか。
<sub>※英語版ではハイフン抜きのosxで、osx-lion osx-marvericksと派生しています。</sub>

もしOSXより前のMacに関する質問が出てきたら・・・英語版には[mac-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-classic)というタグがあるようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今実施しました。

[mac](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac)が[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)に変更されました。