# タグシノニムの提案: os-x ← macos

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

旧来 OS X と呼ばれていたものは、現在では macOS と呼ばれるようになっています。そこで、タグ [macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) を [os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) のシノニム（タグの別名）として登録したいです。

#### 関連

- [macOS#名称](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#.E5.90.8D.E7.A7.B0) -- Wikipedia
- 本家 SO ではシノニムになっています。 https://stackoverflow.com/tags/osx/synonyms
- [タグシノニムの提案：os-x と mac](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2125/19110) -- ja.SO meta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

現在は macOS が正式な名称となっているので、`macos` を正式なタグ、`os-x` を別名にするのが良いと思います。

Comment: macos <- os-x, macos <- mac でシノニムを作成しました。 (もともと os-x <- mac があった)  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all

Comment: @YukiInoue ありがとうございます！　ところで、元々 [os-x] に書かれていたタグ wiki が [macos] には受け継がれないようです。私からは [os-x] の元のタグ wiki を閲覧できないのですが、もし Yuki さんが閲覧できるのであれば [macos] の方に移植して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 仰る通り、もとのタグの wiki は閲覧できない様子でした。一時的にシノニムを解除、テキスト移植、シノニム再設定を行いました。

Answer (score 0):

[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) を正式なタグとした方が良いと思う方はこちらに up-vote をお願いします。