# タグ「macos」と「os-x」のマージ（あるいは、別名の解除）を提案します

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

タグ[macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos)と[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)がマージを必要としています。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge&tab=newest

---

マージとは何なのか、私は推測するのみですが、別名として設定されているタグがマージされていないことにより、観察する限り以下のような影響が出ています。

#### APIへの影響

APIにおけるタグ[macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos)及び、その別名（[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)、[mac](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac)）に対する問い合わせ結果がいろいろとおかしくなっています。
例えば、タグ[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)に関する情報を `/tags/os-x/info` に問い合わせると、別名が設定されているからだと思いますが、タグ[macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos)に関する情報が返ってきます。
http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#order=desc&sort=popular&tags=os-x&filter=default&site=ja.stackoverflow&run=true
しかし、[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) と [macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) は別のタグという扱いですから、今まで [os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) に積み上げられてきた質問は無かったことになり、新参の [macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) でなされた質問のみがカウントされ、`"count": 17` となります。
これを仕様通りと考えるとしても、欲しい情報を得る方法が無い状態です。

#### Webインターフェースへの影響

こういったAPIの挙動はWebインターフェースにも広く影響しています。
例えば検索で `[os-x] is:question` を指定し、タグ[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)を持つ質問を検索しても、17件しか該当しません。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bos-x%5D+is%3Aquestion
これは、APIでタグ[macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos)の情報しか得られないからですね。

#### 運営上の問題

運営上の問題としては、ユーザーがタグ[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)で積み上げたスコアが[macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos)に引き継がれないことにより、新たなタグの別名の推奨といったモデレーション行動が取れなくなることが考えられます。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/macos/topusers
よく分かりませんが、バッジなどにも影響するかも知れません。

---

コメントを受けて追記:
タグ[macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos)と[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)が同一と見なせないということであれば、マージはするべきではなく、タグ別名の設定を取り消すのが正しい対応だと思います。
一度マージされれば、各々のタグを区別して検索することは出来なくなるはずです。

いずれにせよ、APIの挙動を見るかぎり、「別名として設定するが、マージはしない」という状態は想定されていませんので、マージするか別名を解除するか、どちらかが必要です。
モデレーター内で結論に確信が持てない場合は、不可逆な操作を避け、別名の解除を選択するのが無難かと思います。

#### 2018-06-14 追記:

催促するのは気が進まないのですが、API が半年以上壊れたまま、というのはあまり良くないと思います。
上では、

> 不可逆な操作を行いたくない場合は別名の解除を選択するのが無難かと思います。

と書きましたが、正確には「不可逆な操作を行いたくない」かどうか考えている間も（決断に時間がかかるならば）別名を解除しておく必要があります。
つまり、**この状態は放置しておけません**。
今読むと、だいぶ悪文な投稿だったと思います。内容が伝わっていないようでしたら、指摘して下さい。

Comment: マージされるとどうなるのですか？　質問につけられた`os-x`のタグが`macos`に置き換わるのでしょうか。逆にタグシノニムを解除する選択肢はありませんか

Comment: @dokubeko  タグシノニムはむしろ過去提案されて設定されたという経緯を持っていたりします。その時のメタ投稿は次です。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2612/754

Comment: それは既読です。マージの作用がきちんと確認できてから話を進めたかったのですが、じぶんは`os-x`のみを抽出したり除外できないことが不便に思いました。今起きている問題が予期され、十分に議論した上でタグシノニムは設定されましたか？　もしマージが不可逆な操作で取り返しのつかない場合、`os-x`と`macos`を分けて検索する方法が永久に失われないか懸念があります。タグシノニムを解除する選択肢があるか聞いたのはこのためです。`os-x`は`10.11`以前、`macos`は`10.12`以降として大まかに質問のプラットフォームのバージョンを選別して検索する手段であったかもしれないです

Comment: 関係ないかもですが、参考METAの「もともと`os-x <- mac`があった」は[これ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2125/)かと。

Comment: じぶんの希望を言いますと、タグシノニムを解除しない限り`os-x`/`macos`で質問を選別できないのであれば、マージせず、逆に解除してほしいです。現在でも`Mac OS X 10.6`/`OS X 10.10`/`macOS 10.12`を使用しており、下位互換性を確保したアプリを開発する場合には大まかな分類でも検索には大いに助かるからです

Comment: @dokubeko 1意見として回答に記述しては如何でしょう？賛同される方がUpvoteするかもしれません。

Comment: マージしたらどうなるかが未だによくわからないので無理です。前述しているように仮定の話に基づいて懸念を示すのが精一杯です

Comment: [macos] や [osx] はあくまで Windows 等と対比される OS の種類のタグとして使われるべきで、細かいバージョンの差異は [macos-sierra] などの細かいタグで区別すべきだと考えます。ちょうど [python] が [python2] / [python3] を用意しているのと同じです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuki さんとお話しした上で、[os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) を [macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) へマージし、更に [os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) から [macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) へのシノニムを作成しました（新たにシノニムを作成しないと、別の新しいタグとして [os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) を作成できてしまうのです）。

この結果、248個の質問から [os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) が削除され、247個の質問に [macos](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) が付きました。差分はタグが重複して付いていたものです。また、バッジやお気に入りタグ等、タグに関する情報もアップデートされたはずです。

Mac 系 OS 間の差異をタグで表現したい場合は、[macos-sierra](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-sierra) のような形でタグを新規作成し、ご利用ください。

まだ何か不具合がありましたら、新しくメタ投稿頂くか、この回答へコメント頂ければと思います。お待たせしてしまいすいません。機能要求ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 5):

おそらく、タグシノニムは、裏側のデータベースを変えずに表示側・質問作成側でもってなるべく吸収する仕組みの様子ですね。自分が調べたタグシノニムの挙動は下にまとめています。そしてマージは裏側のタグ情報を書き換える操作だったと認識しています。

api に直接問合せる検索が正しく行われないのは、よくないので、問題がなければ、マージを行おうと思っています。

---

#### タグシノニムの挙動

タグシノニムは、自分の観測範囲だと以下の挙動をしていると理解しています。誤解を防ぐために、以下の用語を用います。

> マスター <- シノニム

- 新規にタグを付与する場合に、それがシノニムであった場合は、自動的にマスターでもってタグ付けされます。
- web リソースとして、 url にシノニムタグ名称がある場合、それはマスターの方へリダイレクトされます。

  - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/os-x/info
  - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/os-x/topusers
  - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x
- マスタータグの質問一覧画面について(のみ)は、シノニムについての結果もマージされて取得されます。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos

Comment: マージに賛成します。Meta.SE の FAQ ["What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/341401) および [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119377/341401) を見るに、マージして問題ないように見えます。また、OS バージョン間の差異については SO Meta の ["Rename \[osx\] to \[macos\]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348077/5989200) で議論されているように、[macos-sierra] など別のタグを併用すれば解決されます。

Comment: シノニムの役割については、上にリンクした FAQ と併せて ["How do tag merge requests work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204248/341401) の回答の図が分かりやすかったです。